# Wordpress get terms of specific category of each post and display it

Tags: php, wordpress

What I want to do is get the terms of a specific category of each post and then display it in this post.

Should be simple that the code that I have written:

```
function wodarchive_entry($post_id = null) {

  $post = get_post( $post_id );
  $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category" );
  //Get the terms for this particular item
  $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms

  foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
    $termsString .= $term->name.' ';
    $category_id = $term->parent;//create a string that has all the slugs 
    if($category_id == '203'){
       echo $termsString;
    }
  }             
}
```

Btw, this is not working. Well, almost. It is giving me also values of other categories, probably because the if statement plays until finds the condition.

Comment: you want to display this 203 category id posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get the matching terms in `$termsString` you should place the assignment inside the if-loop.

```
function wodarchive_entry($post_id = null) {
  $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post_id, "category" );
  //Get the terms for this particular item
  $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms

  foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
    $category_id = $term->parent;//create a string that has all the slugs 
    if($category_id == '203'){
       $termsString .= $term->name.' ';
    }
  }
  echo $termsString;                
}
```

Comment: That was so stupid on my part. Thank you very much, couldn't see it. Thanks. By the way, do you think there is a better way to achieve the same thing in wordpress?

Comment: Glad I could help. You could make a Custom Taxonomy to add the terms to, this way you avoid the need to use an if-loop. https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies